# perl discard first array element in map operation

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary, slice, splice

I'm starting to harness the power of perl map, and have run into a question that I couldn't find an answer to. Basically I am parsing the return of a unix command which has a header line that I don't need, and then 2 lines of information per item. Currently, I am doing this:

```
(undef, @ret) = map { [split /\n/] } split(/(?:Host: )/, `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`);
```

Which works fine to skip the header and give me one array element per "useful" line of text. However, I want to build a hash instead, which I would know how to do except for that extra line. So how can I, in a single line of code, ignore that first array element, to allow me to create the hash? I was thinking somewhere along the lines of a slice or a splice, but I would need to know the size of the array created by the split on Host (is that possible?). I guess I could also do a (undef,undef, %ret) = map {...} but if this could be done with a slice or a splice, that would be great to learn how.

Comment: Don't get too wrapped with doing things "in a single line of code." Readable code where the intent is clear is much easier to maintain than code awkwardly forced into a single line. To read a config file into a hash, it's generally better to `open` the file and read the contents in a `while` loop, processing as you go. What do you want to use for the hash keys in this case?

Comment: I will be using the host number as key. Though I am trying to do this in a single line, my desire is mostly to learn how to get back a list (not array) slice skipping certain elements.

Comment: That won't work, since multiple devices can share the same host.

Comment: You mean that they can use the same host but be on different channels? For my current (simple) application that won't be an issue, since it is just meant to add the host, so host is all I need

Comment: Look at the example file in the [CentOS page](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-dir-scsi.html) on `/proc/scsi`. If you're only using a hash to get the *unique* host names, that approach will work; otherwise you'll need to pick something that won't clobber existing keys in the hash.

Comment: Yeah I had been looking at that page but the formatting misled me to not see the fact that hosts are shared, however, for my purposes I think it doesn't matter since all I will be using this for is to add and remove a removable drive on the SCSI bus via its host (since my motherboard doesn't send a "host added" signal). But it's good to know that hosts are shared, thanks, I will keep that in mind as I keep developing this script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to remove the first element from a [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and still be able to chain a more commands would be to use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) with a state variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = do {
    my $line = 0;
    grep {++$line > 1} split /\n/, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n"
};

print "@lines";
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

However, I think you're trying to do too much in a single line of code.

Since it appears you're just reading a file, I would suggest that you use Perl to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file instead of shelling out to `cat`.

Assuming your key / value delimiter is a colon, the following is how I'd recommend you construct your logic:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %hash = do {
    open my $fh, '<', '/proc/scsi/scsi';
    <$fh>; # Skip Header Row
    map {chomp; split /:/, $_, 2} <$fh>
};
```

Comment: Watch out for the use of `state` inside of `grep` (and `map`, etc).  It only initializes once, so if that `grep` is run more than once (for example, by calling a function multiple times) you may not get what you hope for.  Try this: `do { grep { state $line = 0 ; $line++ ; print $line, ' ' } 0..1 } for 0..1;` You'll get "1 2 3 4", not "1 2 1 2".

Comment: Yes, I was offering that as a choice purely in the context of a single use script, not as a reusable function call.  However, I've went ahead and reworked it since I don't want to model bad technique, especially since I'm advocating not doing chained commands anyway.

Comment: The grep {++$line > 1}, and the do {} are very interesting and useful approaches, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

heh, well, it seems it was indeed as easy as I thought, I had just forgotten about the -1 index position, so, the solution for anyone that might be interested in doing something like this is:

```
@ret = map { [split /\n/] } (split(/(?:Host: )/, `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`))[1,-1];
```

to get it to skip the first array element returned by the split on Host.

---

*(The above is completely wrong, as pointed out by @M42, keeping it there for reference only.)*

For those interested, this is the final code I came up with (based on @Miller's awesome approach, with some simplifications) to my problem:

```
my $i;
my $split_RE = qr(\S+|ANSI  SCSI revision); # you can create the precise list of keys here
my %attached = map {
        chomp;
        my ($host, %infohash) = split(/\s*($split_RE):\s*/);
        ($host => {%infohash} ) # FIXME: one host can have multiple devices.. an array with push() needs to be used here.. somehow (might have to avoid use of map)
        } 
    grep{$i++} # remove/ignore first line
    (split(/(?:Host: )/, `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`));
```

I still need to address the host clobberin' time, as pointed out by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, but this is not urgent to my problem, and should turn out to be straight-forward if not trivial.

Comment: Be carefull that `[1,-1]` return the second and the last element only.

Comment: oh hmm.. then I'm not sure how to do this then.

Comment: Just do like your first atempt or, in 2 lines: `@ret = map ...; shift @ret;`

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to do it in a slice?

Comment: Of course yoou could but it produces unreadable code. Have a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html

Comment: But splice doesn't work on lists, only on arrays. I tried something like: my @arr = splice (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 1, -1; and it says "Type of arg 1 to splice must be array (not constant item)"

Comment: then wrap it in an array:  `splice( @{[ 1..7 ]}, 1, -1)`  but that gets rid of both the first and last elements; there is no way to tell slice to slice through the end.  You'd have to pick an arbitrarily large number `splice( @{[ 1..7 ]}, 1, 999999999)` or add a dummy element `splice( @{[ 1..7, undef ]}, 1, -1 )`.   assigning to (undef,undef,%hash) would be much preferable.

Comment: @insaner Sure, there are other novel ways to remove the first element from a list in a single statement, like `my @trimmed = grep { state $keep++ } qw(foo bar baz);` But if somebody ever used something like that in code that I had to maintain instead of `my @trimmed = qw(foo bar baz); shift @trimmed;`, I would probably have an aneurysm.

Comment: @ysth The de-referencing of anon list ... is that to make it portable? In newer versions (>=5.14), `splice` supports anon lists.

Comment: @jaypal ? no it doesn't

Comment: oh, you mean anonymous arrays?  ["This aspect of splice is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl."](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.21.1/pod/perlfunc.pod#splice)

Comment: @ysth sorry yes I meant anon arrays. Hmm... I was under the impression that features that are experimental don't remain experimental if they are present in the next major release. `:)` thanks for the link though.