# perl list subset range

Tags: perl, list

In another question I was asking, I was trying to find a way to get a subset list (or array) from a list, thinking this could be done with a slice or a splice. With an array it is as trivial as:

```
@arr[2 .. $#arr]
```

to get an array that has all the same elements starting from the element at index 2 to the end (ie, skipping the first 2 elements). However, how could this be done with a list, where you cannot use something like $#arr (since lists have no names). So here's the question, is it possible to do such a thing with a list without resorting to copying to arrays or using multiple lines of code? Is there some simple notation to just extract an arbitrary length list that reaches the *end* of the list (without needing to know the length of the list beforehand)? In other words something like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)[1 .. -1];
```

(which obviously doesn't work) to get

```
(2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

does such a notation or function exist (for lists)?

Comment: I don't believe it exists built-in, but you can write it as a very short function.

Comment: You can create an anonymous array reference and take a `splice` for eg: `print "$_\n" for splice( [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ], 1 );`

Comment: @jaypal, That copies every single scalar. My version only copies a C pointer per scalar.

Comment: @ikegami You are right. Already up voted your answer. `:)` still a lot to learn.

Comment: Just curious as to why you would want to do this in the first place. What is the use case?

Comment: @Zaid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270236/perl-discard-first-array-element-in-map-operation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sub { @_[1..$#_] }->( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 )
```

Comment: ... or you could make the function even shorter and anonymous and call it right in the same expression. Clever :)

Comment: @ikegami: So cool! My first thought is something like `perl -e 'print +(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)[1..sub{~~@_}->(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]'`

Comment: @Gnouc, Repeating the expression that generates the list is a very bad idea. It's error prone, and the actual list generator could be expensive and could have side-effects.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, I know that. That's why I don't post an answer. Just to emphasis how clever your answer is!

Comment: Wow! cool! I didn't know you could do that with a sub. Thanks! I will wait to see if anyone else has a different approach before I accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing a bit on ikegami's solution:

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
my @b = sub { @_[1..$#_] }->(@a);
```

b is now (2,3,4,5,6,7)

** You can also use splice() to do this in a more straightforward way:  **

```
my @c = @a;
splice (@c, 0, 1, ());
```

c is now (2,3,4,5,6,7)